# Which weight training exercise to do so I can grow my upper trapezius?

Tags: muscle-mass

My aim is to build my upper back so it looks like what highlighted in red in these pictures.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The vocabulary is only a Google search away. https://i.imgur.com/Qk30Huz.jpg If you could rephrase your question after taking a look at the names, that would increase the chance of getting good answers.

Comment: While I agree with the spirit of what you’re saying, @Alec (educating onesself to ask better questions), I can’t imagine him referring to anything other than the upper traps.

Comment: @JustSnilloc - Completely agree. One of the motivations would be that editing the question with proper vocabulary would increase the flow of people who land here from Google searches, which is where a lot of good answers come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Training the traps is what you're looking for.

Exercises you should look at:

- Face pulls
- Shrugs
- Upright rows
- Deadlifts (not isolation but still builds pretty much everything on your back)

Comment: +1 for deadlifts. The insane isometric work on the traps is a godsend for building muscles that simply look more muscular.

Comment: You could probably add Farmer's Walk to this list too.